# jquery: avoid too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, recursion

I have a script that distribute the 54 playing cards randomly on 4 players, it will generate 2 random numbers to get a random card, the category number (from 1 to 4) which means: "hearts,spades,diamonds,clubs", and the card number (from 1 to 13).

The problem is there are too much recursions in this script, so how I can avoid this error by calling the functions in threads or something similar?

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var human = [];
    var east = [];
    var west = [];
    var north = [];
    var used_cards = [];

    distributeCards(north,$('#north'));
    distributeCards(east,$('#east'),'vertical');
    distributeCards(west,$('#west'));
    distributeCards(human,$('#south'));

    function distributeCards(array,container,view){
        for(var i = 0; i < 13; i++){
            var category,card;
            do{
                var uniqueCard = uniqueRandomCard();
            }while(typeof uniqueCard === "undefined")
            category = uniqueCard[0];
            card = uniqueCard[1];
            array.push(uniqueCard);
            var category_name = '';
            if(category === 1){
                category_name = 'hearts';
            }
            else if(category === 2){
                category_name = 'spades';
            }
            else if(category === 3){
                category_name = 'diamonds';
            }
            else if(category === 4){
                category_name = 'clubs';
            }
            if(card === 1){
                card = 'ace';
            }
            else if(card === 11){
                card = 'jack';
            }
            else if(card === 12){
                card = 'queen';
            }
            else if(card === 13){
                card = 'king';
            }
            if(view === 'vertical'){
                $(container).children('.row').append('<img src="cards/backRotate.png" class="card"/>');
            }
            else if(view === 'horizontal'){
                $(container).children('.row').append('<img src="cards/back.png" class="card"/>');
            }
        }
    }
    function randomNumberFromRange(min,max){
        return Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min);
    }
    function uniqueRandomCard(){
        var card = randomNumberFromRange(1, 13);
        var category = randomNumberFromRange(1, 4);
        if(!inAssocArray(category,card,used_cards)){
            var array = [];
            array[0] = category;
            array[1] = card;
            used_cards.push(array);
            return array;
        }
        else{
            uniqueRandomCard();
        }
    }
    function inAssocArray(key,value,array){
        var flag = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i][0] === key && array[i][1]=== value){
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your uniqueRandomCard() function seems to be the only one with recursion, and it has a logical error in that it when it calls itself it doesn't do anything with the return value. You cope with that via the while loop in the other function that checks for undefined, but wouldn't it be better to fix it directly? But I don't know why you use recursion there at all - couldn't you just use a while loop inside uniqueRandomCard()?

Comment: @nnnnnn it should be called recursively, till it return a value that is not found in the `used_cards` array

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah, the while loop would be a better idea, how I didn't think to try it!! thanks

Comment: In my opinion a better solution would be to put all the possible cards in a `deck` array, implement a `shuffle()` method, and then deal by taking cards off the top of the deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing recursion the way you've implemented it is quite easy.  Simply replace your call and if statement with a while statement.

```
function uniqueRandomCard(){
  var card = randomNumberFromRange(1, 13);
  var category = randomNumberFromRange(1, 4);
  while(inAssocArray(category,card,used_cards)) {
    card = randomNumberFromRange(1, 13);
    category = randomNumberFromRange(1, 4);
  }
  var array = [];
  array[0] = category;
  array[1] = card;
  used_cards.push(array);
  return array;
}
```

That being said there are some fundamental better ways of handling limited sets like this.  Storing unused cards and randomly selecting from that is far superior.